# Calling a script in any programming language from CLI vs Desktop

Tags: php, python, command-line-interface

I have created some scripts though out my programming work cycle and noticed a strange behaviour. When calling them from Command line interface they execute much faster rather than when I call them from desktop (Windows 10 x64).

For example

`curl http://www.example/script.php` - will run 2 times faster than browsing with chrome/firefox.....
`php /path/to/php/script.php` - will run even faster.

Does this make sense? Why?

Comment: How much faster is "faster" here? Are we talking about 100 vs 200 ms? Or a minute versus 10 minutes?

Comment: @ceejayoz 3-4 times faster wanted to to say. Like instead of 3 mins will execute in 1 min

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. 100 to 400 ms and 1 minute to 4 minutes are totally different things. *About* how long do the scripts take, per your benchmarking?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That certainly seems abnormal. Steps I'd take: check the time-to-first-byte in your browser's inspector. If that's normal, move onto profiling with something like Xdebug or Blackfire.io to see what's taking so long.